# N fold cross validation in weka for tweet classification

Tags: twitter, classification, weka, text-mining, document-classification

My aim is to use weka to classify a bunch of tweets to a predefined set of 3 classes(say news,education,sports)

In this case training set and testing set are different.(Training lengthy web pages, Testing just one or two line tweets).

How to perform 'N' fold cross validation for this problem.

do i need to mix up training and testing data set to makeup a single file and apply 'n' fold cross validation or do i need to train the classifier first and then apply 'n' fold cross validation for the test set in weka.

I presume the latter makes sense but i am not sure.Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of your data should be the same in training and set set. This requirement make the N-fold cross-validation technique usable.

For the problems related to the model selection, have a look at this:
https://vimeo.com/29569892